# Query while declaring Flask Blueprint

Tags: python, flask, design-patterns, blueprint

I have been using flask for a while. I made an app implementing the application factory design pattern, but I can't understand the use of `boo` in the below-mentioned code.

```
from flask import Blueprint

some_blueprint = Blueprint("boo", __name__)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter of the Blueprint constructor (in your case `boo`) is simply a symbolic name that you assign to the Blueprint object.

Check out this link: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/views/